# How to set min-width to image in fixed container?

Tags: html, css

I have image which is responsive and centered in the middle of the page as vertically and horizontally.But problem is when I make it smaller,its getting smaller after 1014px width.How can I make it bigger than 1014px?I want it to be smaller later as there is gap from left and right still.

Position should be fixed because Im gonna add scrollable nav menu to the left later.And that nav should be scrollable when this image container has `fixed` position

For you to understand my problem better you can see the image below

[image]

```css
 *,*::after,*::before{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
    font-size:62,5%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
 body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
 .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .imgContainer{
    max-width: 900px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
        
        <title>ImageProcessing Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
             <div class="imgContainer">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't set a `max-width` to the container... and set a width in percent (like 90%). Then add to the image `width:100%` and it should be done

```css
*,*::after,*::before{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
    font-size:62,5%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}
 body{
    box-sizing: border-box;
} 
 .responsive {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
  .imgContainer{
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width:90%;
  }
  img  {width:100%}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/favicon.png">
        
        <title>ImageProcessing Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
             <div class="imgContainer">
                  <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/257360/pexels-photo-257360.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thankx very much

Answer (score 1):

Change the max-width to 500px – the same as the image width –, then add `width: 100%` to the `.imgContainer` element.

```
.imgContainer {
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 4px solid yellow;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

Also, change the display of the img (block) to remove the extra space below by default.

```
.responsive {
    display: block;
}
```